# Program to enter 5 student mark across 4 subjects and output highest average mark of student and subject

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a program where i need to be able to enter 5 student marks across 4 different subjects and then output the highest average mark of both the student and the subject.

The desired input and output is :

```
Student 1 (courses 1-4): 50 60 70 60 
Student 2 (courses 1-4): 100 90 87 90
Student 3 (courses 1-4): 70 100 90 90
Student 4 (courses 1-4): 30 65 50 50
Student 5 (courses 1-4): 58 50 74 43
The highest average mark of students: 91.75
The highest average mark of courses: 74.2
```

The current code I have works for calculating for one subject and not 4. How am I able to enter 4 grades per student to get my desired output.

see my code below:

```
m1 = int(input("Student 1 (courses 1-4): "))
m2 = int(input("Student 2 (courses 1-4): "))
m3 = int(input("Student 3 (courses 1-4): "))
m4 = int(input("Student 4 (courses 1-4): "))
m5 = int(input("Student 5 (courses 1-4): "))

avg = (m1 + m2+ m3+ m4 + m5) / 5;
avg1 =(m1 + m2+ m3+ m4 + m5) / 20;
print("The Highest average mark of students =", avg)
print("The Highest average mark of courses =", avg1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a dictionary to take the inputs of marks for each student. Lets call it `d_marks`. Create a dictionary to get the average of all students. Let's call it `avg_marks`. Create a dictionary to get the total marks of all courses. Let's call it `avg_course`. After that get the `max` of them. Here's how you can do it:

```
d_marks = {}
avg_marks = {}
avg_course = {}
for i in range(1,6): # We loop for 5 students
    d_marks[f'Student {i} (courses 1-4)'] = list(map(int, input(f"Student {i} (courses 1-4): ").split())) # Split the string and creates an integer list
    avg_marks[f'Average of Student {i}'] = sum(d_marks[f'Student {i} (courses 1-4)']) / len(d_marks[f'Student {i} (courses 1-4)']) #Create average dictionary for Students
    for j in range(1, len(d_marks[f'Student {i} (courses 1-4)'])+1):
        if f'Course {j} sum' in avg_course: # if course sum already in dictionary then add it to previous. 
            avg_course[f'Course {j} sum'] += d_marks[f'Student {i} (courses 1-4)'][j-1]
        else:
            avg_course[f'Course {j} sum'] = d_marks[f'Student {i} (courses 1-4)'][j-1] # if course sum not in dictionary then create one. 

print("The Highest average mark of students =", max(avg_marks.values()))
print("The Highest average mark of courses =", max(avg_course.values())/ len(d_marks))
```

Output:

```
Student 1 (courses 1-4): 50 60 70 60
Student 2 (courses 1-4): 100 90 87 90
Student 3 (courses 1-4): 70 100 90 90
Student 4 (courses 1-4): 30 65 50 50
Student 5 (courses 1-4): 58 50 74 43
The Highest average mark of students = 91.75
The Highest average mark of courses = 74.2
```

Answer (score 2):

This code does the job,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Part 1
student_num = 5
all_marks = []

for i in range(student_num):
  marks = input(f"Student {i + 1} (courses 1-4): ")
  all_marks.append(list(map(float, marks.split(" "))))

# Part 2
df = pd.DataFrame(all_marks, columns = ['Marks'])
course_avg = df.Marks.apply(np.mean)
student_avg = df.Marks.apply(np.mean, axis = 1)
```

The first part of the code converts the input into numbers and stores them into a list. This list is then converted into a data frame in Part 2. I firstly apply `np.mean` on the columns to find the average for each course, then on the rows to find the average for each student.

You can use `idxmax()` on both `course_avg` and `student_avg` to find the index of the maximum average and find the course/student with the highest average accordingly.

***(It's better to store the values in a .xlsx or .csv file directly instead of inputing them through Python this way. Once you have the files, just pass the file path in `pd.read_excel()` or `pd.read_csv()` depending upon the format of the file.)***